# Assigning a large number of variables (from a lookup table?)

Tags: r, variable-assignment, lookup

I have a two-column lookup table with names in the first column and non-sequential numbers in the second column:

```
Name    Number
ArcBo     16
ArcGl     41
BorSa    534
EleGr    121
GadMa    249
GadMo    448
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to pass a name to my script, and get the script to return the name's associated number. I envisioned doing something similar to building a dictionary in Python, by perhaps using a hash, but I'm still fairly new to **R** and environments appear to be quite challenging. Is there another way to approach this? I tried the ultimate simple solution of iterating through the table as follows:

```
for (i in (1:nrow(lookupTable))){
+ lookupTable[i,2] <- lookupTable[i,1]
+ }
```

but all that does is replace the number with the name, such that I have two columns of names and no numbers.

Comment: You could store it as a data.frame. Then, you can access the number corresponding to a give name by: `DF$Number[DF$Name == "ArcBo"]` for example.

Comment: Since you are new here you might want to read [**the about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how SO works. StackOverflow is made **much** more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem, you accept it by clicking the little check mark. You are under absolutely **no** obligation to do so, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did in fact solve your problem and helps to keep the site clean by removing answered question from the unanswered questions stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lookuptab[lookuptab$Name==lookupvalue,2]
```

Or, as a function:

```
lookup <- function(lookupvalue)
    lookuptab[lookuptab$Name==lookupvalue,2]
lookup("ArcBo")
lookup("GadMa")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function this should work as you want:

```
flookup <- function(x , df , lkup = 1 , ret = 2 ){
return( df[ df[,lkup] %in% x , ret ] )
}
```

You can specify the lookup value, `x`, the `data.frame` to look it up in `df`, the column for the lookup, `lkup` and the column to return from `ret`.

```
flookup( "ArcBo" , df , 1 , 2 )
# [1] 16
```

It gives you some flexibility to look up multiple names at once if you so wish:

```
flookup( c("ArcBo" , "EleGr") , df , 1 , 2 )
# [1]  16 121
```

Answer (score 0):

The qdap library uses an environment (hash) lookup that is very easy to use.

Here I've taken your problem and made up a vector of values to lookup:

```
lookupTable <- read.table(text="Name    Number
ArcBo     16
ArcGl     41
BorSa    534
EleGr    121
GadMa    249
GadMo    448", header=TRUE)

I_want_2_look_u_up <- sample(lookupTable$Name, 25, T)


## > I_want_2_loo_u_up
##  [1] ArcBo ArcBo EleGr ArcGl GadMa ArcBo ArcGl ArcGl ArcGl GadMo GadMa ArcGl
## [13] ArcBo GadMo ArcBo BorSa ArcGl ArcGl GadMo ArcGl GadMo ArcBo EleGr GadMo
## [25] GadMa
## Levels: ArcBo ArcGl BorSa EleGr GadMa GadMo

library(qdap)
lookup(I_want_2_look_u_up, lookupTable)

## > lookup(I_want_2_look_u_up, lookupTable)
##  [1]  16  16 121  41 249  16  41  41  41 448 249  41  16 448  16 534  41  41 448
## [20]  41 448  16 121 448 249
```